# Azure B2C - Does using a hidden iFrame in a Web App work with a B2C Tenant?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When you review Vittorio’s article concerning id_tokens

Controlling a Web App’s session duration - http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/

He mentions using a hidden iFrame to renew the id_token.

```
<script> 
        setInterval( function () 
                { @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                        <text> 
                                var renewUrl = "/Account/ForcedSignIn"; 
                                    var element = document.getElementById("renewSession"); 
                                    console.log("sending request to: " + renewUrl); 
                                    element.src = renewUrl; 
                    </text> 
                    } else { 
                            <text> 
                                console.log("No renewal attempt without a valid session"); 
                            </text> 
                    }, 
                    1000*60*45
            );
    </script>
```

Will something like this work with a B2C Tenant?  When implementing this same solution in B2C, it does not work.  When viewing the network requests with dev tools I can I can see that it does call my endpoint to invoke the challenge request, then I see the call out to authorize (which is similar to what happens when initially logging in) but it never returns from there.  Even though when viewing the response from the authorize call it seems to have succeeded? It just never returns to my RedirectUri (and thus I never get the renew token).

HTTP 302  GET  http://localhost:54786/Authentication/ForcedSignIn

HTTP 200 https://login.microsoftonline.com/te//b2c_policy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54786%2FAuthentication%2FForcedSignInRedirect&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties...

No response is returned?  Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C allows a hidden frame to be used to renew tokens so you might have to check a few things with the "renewal" URL:

1) It must begin with your tenant name and your policy name:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?..`

2) It must include the `prompt=none` query string parameter:

`?..&prompt=none`

It is this `prompt` parameter being set to `none` that allows the hidden frame to renew tokens.

Comment: Tried adding both to the script and it did not work.